# Usar preg_match_all() en un Array (Notice: Array to string conversion in) php

Tags: php, array, string

Busco ayuda para resolver el mensaje:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in

```
<?php
 $response = '{"data":[{"access_token":"EAAby7f21xKABALPCThZC63i4LZAHZC7MaYbQ0E5gN","id":"515968102105625"},{"access_token":"EAAby7f21xKABAK0zyfHCVNBE0Nn3g1XZCWuXzZA4T","id":"1338263602879836"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"NTE1OTY4MTAyMTA1NjI1","after":"MTMzODI2MzYwMjg3OTgzNgZDZD"}}}';

    if (preg_match_all('#"access_token":[^"]*"([^"]*)"#', $response, $datos)) {
        $mp = $datos[1];
    } else {
        $mp = 'error';
    }
    echo $mp;

    ?>
```

Busco la manera de obtener los **access_token** de la variable **$response**
Espero su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al cumplir con la condición de la expresión regular , la variable `$mp` será un `array` es por eso que al intentar imprimir con `echo` lanza el error. Lo más conveniente sería manejar un tipo de dato para las dos opciones posibles *(if.. else)*

```
$response = '{"data":[{"access_token":"EAAby7f21xKABALPCThZC63i4LZAHZC7MaYbQ0E5gN","id":"515968102105625"},{"access_token":"EAAby7f21xKABAK0zyfHCVNBE0Nn3g1XZCWuXzZA4T","id":"1338263602879836"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"NTE1OTY4MTAyMTA1NjI1","after":"MTMzODI2MzYwMjg3OTgzNgZDZD"}}}';

if (preg_match_all('#"access_token":[^"]*"([^"]*)"#', $response, $datos)) {
    $mp = $datos[1];
} else {
    // Tipo array con clave error.
    $mp = array('error' => 'No existen Access Tokens');
}
```

Y para imprimir sería.

```
print_r($mp);
```

Si desea en `String` , podría emplear `implode`

```
echo implode(',',$mp);
```

Para evitar expresiones regulares para este caso , solo podría haber hecho uso de [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) para convertir el String JSON que tiene un `array` y así poder acceder directamente *(si como segundo parámetro se le envía true el retorno lo convierte en array caso contrario en objetos)*

```
foreach (json_decode($response)->data as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->access_token."<br>";
}
```

Sí desea separar cada valor en variables , **sí solo tendría 2 valores `access_token` para todos los casos**. caso contrario sugeriría seguir guardando los valores en `Array`

```
//Convierte en array asociativo con True de segundo parámetro
$newResponse = json_decode($response,TRUE)['data'];
$varone = $newResponse[0]['access_token'];
$vartwo = $newResponse[1]['access_token'];
```

Comment: Gracias por el dato solo tengo una duda como separo cada valor del **access_token** en una variable diferente usando **implode(',',$mp);**

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions revise mi actualización. Separar en variables los valores sería innecesario , para tales casos se crearon los `arrays` , igualmente sugerí una solución en el caso que solo tenga 2 `access_tokens`